# Printed information on form changes after I switch accounts

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a profile page with blanks like username, city, country etc. I have successfully stored username & city in the Database using the `UPDATE` query. I have set the `WHERE` condition according to the email of the users. I have made 2 accounts with separates emails, for testing purposes. When I logged in from account #1, entered username & id, it was successfully stored in the correct row. Then I logged out, and logged in from account #2, and the username & city I entered in account #1 was duplicated and printed on blanks of account #2. But in database, the data was still distinguished until I pressed ENTER. So my question is, why is this happening and how do I fix this?

**This is the action.php:**

```
<?php
session_start(); //---> start session
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'id1753243_venom', 'roushan123', 'id1753243_gameware_01');
if(!$con)
{
    echo 'Not connected to the server';
}

$city = $_SESSION['city'];
$city = $_POST['city'];

if(isset($_POST['username']))
if(isset($_POST['city']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username)."', city = '$city' WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_SESSION['email'])."‌​'";
    $insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //---> this will store username into session variable
    $_SESSION['city'] = $city; //---> this will store city into session variable
}

if(!$insert)
{
    echo 'Not inserted';
}
else
{
    echo 'Inserted';
}
header("refresh:2; url=user.php");
?>
```

This is my **HTML Form:**

```
                      <form method="POST" action="action.php">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Username</label>
                                        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>City</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City" value="<?php echo $city; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right">Update Profile</button>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </form>
```

**NOTE:** I know the code is not secure, this is just for test purposes.

**NOTE #2:** This duplication only occurs with *City* & *Username*, other blanks e.g email, first name & last name are working fine. Feel free to point out mistakes! Thanks in advance!

Comment: While updating the records you're not distinguishing account #1 from account #2 in the `WHERE` clause, you should use the `$_SESSION['email']` of that particular account in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The entries in database for account #1 & account #2 are still different but they are not different on the form. If this is what you meant above, can you tell me how the query line should look like?

Comment: *"I know the code is not secure, this is just for test purposes."*  If you don't get in the habit of simply writing all code in a secure fashion, then sooner or later something you wrote "just for test" is going to survive into production.